# EWS get selected mail from exchnage server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, mail-server

I am fetching all the mails from exhange server using EWS and showing in a grid. When a user clicks on the mail i have to fetch all the details from the server and show.
How to fetch a specific mail from exchange server using its conversationId or any unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use messageid which is unique  to every email.You can then use the messageid to find the mailitem that u r looking from the entire list of  emails in the mailbox(assuming u already have the code to get all the emails from a mailbox using EWS ,which u use to populate the grid view).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are after:

```cs
// Assuming you already know what the ItemId is
ItemId i;

// Defines the properties returned for the EmailMessage, can also add ExtendedProperties to this.
PropertySet ps = PropertySet.FirstClassProperties;

// Accesing all properties
EmailMessage mail = EmailMessage.Bind(
    Program.ExConn.Service, 
    new ItemId(i.UniqueId), 
    ps);
```

Note that the `ItemId` changes if the `EmailMessage` has moved folders, so you may get a  `ServiceResponseException` with the `ErrorCode` of `ServiceError.ErrorItemNotFound`